# How can I write an R function with two conditions?

Tags: r, function, printing, sample

Lets say that I want to make an R function to pick a 6 random numbers to give a winner of a raffle. The raffle consists of number 1 to 70, I want to randomly pick 7 numbers from that range and then I want to pick one random number from 1 to 26 (ill called lucky number). All six numbers should be printed everytime I run the function.

I tried to make a sample with "winning numbers" and "lucky number" but I get an error. And once I try to make a function I get more than 6 numbers

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help improve your post, it would be better to include the code you have attempted. So that we can work with your existing progress.

Comment: I'm confuse on the sequence. You say you want to pick 6 random numbers. But your first step says you will pick 7 numbers then pick one more random number. Anyway doing a raffle in R is as simple as `sample( 1:70, size = 7, replacement = FALSE)`

Comment: Just use `sample`. Its default is not to use replacement and that is what you need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.